# 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, numpy

I've been following a video tutorial on python, and I received an attribute error regardless typing the exact same code as the video.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[56.0, 0.0, 4,4, 68.0],
             [1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0],
             [1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9]])

cal = A.sum(axis=0)
percentage = 100*A/cal.reshape(1,4)
print(percentage)
```

The attribute error points to the percentage variable, stating that the list has no attribute 'reshape'. I searched for solutions and saw on the documentation that it has been "*Deprecated since version 0.19.0. Calling this method will raise an error. Please call .values.reshape(...) instead.*", and I tried the updated one according to what the documentation had provided.

```
percentage = 100*A/cal.values.reshape(1,4)
```

After this attempt, it still led to an attribute error. I don't know if I did it wrong because I'm completely new to python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this warning:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested
> sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays
> with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do
> this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.   A =
> np.array([[56.0, 0.0, 4,4, 68.0],

And according to this question:
[numpy.VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980867/numpy-visibledeprecationwarning-creating-an-ndarray-from-ragged-nested-sequence)

This has to do with the creation of arrays from lists of unequal length. So I presume that in this line:

```
[56.0, 0.0, 4,4, 68.0]
```

The 4,4 should have been a 4.4, right?

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the typo. I'm gonna use a better IDE from now on that will make me aware of such typos.

Answer (score 4):

You first list has one more item (5 vs 4 for the others). This makes it an `object` array with **python lists as elements** (and you get a `VisibleDeprecationWarning` warning).

Thus cal becomes a concatenation of the lists (`[56.0, 0.0, 4, 4, 68.0, 1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0, 1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9]`) instead of a numpy array, triggering your error.

I imagine this might be a typo and changing `4,4` to `4.4` gives the following output:

```py
A = np.array([[56.0, 0.0, 4.4, 68.0],
              [1.2, 104.0, 52.0, 8.0],
              [1.8, 135.0, 99.0, 0.9],])

cal = A.sum(axis=0)
# array([ 59. , 239. , 155.4,  76.9])

percentage = 100*A/cal.reshape(1,4)
print(percentage)
```

output:

```
[[94.91525424  0.          2.83140283 88.42652796]
 [ 2.03389831 43.51464435 33.46203346 10.40312094]
 [ 3.05084746 56.48535565 63.70656371  1.17035111]]
```

Comment: "I imagine this might be a typo" -- isn't that a reason to vote to close?

Comment: @John the question is well asked, I think it deserved an answer with details

Comment: seems reasonable

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks, the typo has been fixed and it works.